# Delete Sheet/chart event VBA

Tags: vba, excel, events

I am trying to trigger a macro when a sheet (Excel) is deleted.
Since 2010 there are different delete events:

Application Level: The Application.SheetBeforeDelete event.

Workbook Level: The Workbook.SheetBeforeDelete event.

Worksheet Level: The Worksheet.BeforeDelete event.

As a beginner I was not able to apply the last two well, however I tried to apply the first one.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDelete(ByVal Sh As Object) 
Call Macro
End Sub
```

This works fine on sheets, but it doesn't work on charts (sheets that only contain a chart).

My goal is to adjust my counter and possibly rename the sheets, as my sheets are named Sheetname(1),..(2).. and the user frequently deletes sheets.

I searched a lot but I couldn't find any examples that I could follow.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I suspect this is a bug. Certainly seems like it to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's looks like an implementation oversight, this event should have been implemented according to the design. In fact, the `Sheets` collection is the union of the `Worksheets` and `Charts` collections. Since the name of the event is `Workbook_SheetBeforeDelete` (not `Workbook_WorksheetBeforeDelete`), common sense dictates that the event should apply to all `Sheets`, that is, both `Worksheets` and `Charts`.

Notice that, other events such as `Workbook_SheetDeactivate` are raised for both Charts and Worksheets. This confirms the error but also suggests a workaround by exploiting the `Workbook_SheetDeactivate` event.

We can add two procedures to `ThisWorkbook` code module. `checkChartDelete()` checks if a chart has been deleted and launches the appropriate action. It needs to be called through `Application.OnTime`, so it gets its parameter through a static variable `chartNameToCheck`.

```
' Code Module ThisWorkbook
Option Explicit
Private chartNameToCheck As String
Private Sub checkChartDelete()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim x: Set x = Sheets(chartNameToCheck)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        '**********************************************
        ' call or do here the action on chart deleted '
        '**********************************************
        MsgBox "chart deleted: " & chartNameToCheck
    End If
    chartNameToCheck = ""
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If TypeName(Sh) <> "Chart" Then Exit Sub
    chartNameToCheck = Sh.name
    Application.OnTime Now, "ThisWorkbook.checkChartDelete"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the code, it works perfectly.

Comment: I noticed that if the Sub chartNameToCheck was situated in another module, it is not possible to use the variable chartNameToCheck, is there a way to overcome that?

Comment: @Bambuchka both the `chartNameToCheck` static variable and the  `checkChartDelete` routine can be moved to a standard code moduel. They'll need to be public (which is already the case, although they could better be private inside the WB), and the defeered call should be changed into this Application.OnTime Now, "checkChartDelete" (removing `ThisWorkbook.`)