# Delete/Add sheets event - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any event which triggered on sheet deletion AND addition? i have try

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
End Sub
```

but this event works only when i add a sheet. In my case i need something to works in both Add & Delete.

Any help will appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another way

**Logic**:

1. Before the sheet is deleted, count the number of sheets in the workbook
2. When a sheet is activated, check the number of sheets in the workbook

**Code**:

```
Dim PreviousWorksheetCount As Integer

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim CurrentWorksheetCount As Integer

    CurrentWorksheetCount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    If CurrentWorksheetCount < PreviousWorksheetCount Then
        MsgBox "Sheet was deleted"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDelete(ByVal Sh As Object)
    PreviousWorksheetCount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
End Sub
```

Comment: No @sancho.s You suggested a timer like Zsmaster. My code does not use a timer object :)

Comment: I suggested both, a timer, and a counter of Sheets as a better option: "...Even better, you may set up a waiting loop that counts the number of sheets in the workbook..."

Comment: @sancho.s: Honestly, I did not even read your post. I hardly read posts which do not have VBA code in it. I did read Zsmaster's code and also commented on it. But if you think my post "stole" your idea then please feel free to downvote it. I will not mind :)

Comment: I don't think it "steals" the idea, and I would not downvote... In the end, the objective is that votes reflect usefulness.
On the contrary, if you think the code you posted embodies the idea in my answer, it would perhaps be good that you start your post with a suitable reference and related text.

Comment: @sancho.s `On the contrary, if you think the code you posted embodies the idea in my answer, it would perhaps be good that you start your post with a suitable reference` If I had read your post before I posted and if my answer was based on your post., I would have definitely (gladly) given the reference. Since that is not the case, I can't give that reference...

Comment: You did not have that information at the time of posting, but you do have it now, and you are always free to edit, so I guess `you can give that reference`. Edits for good (whenever there is new info available) are always welcome...

Answer (score 2):

Here you are a delete sheet event.

Put this code in a standard code module

```
Public shName As String

Sub Deletesheet()
    Dim oWS As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWS = Sheets(shName)
    If oWS Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox shName & " has been deleted"
    End If
End Sub
```

Put this in ThisWorkbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal sh As Object)
    shName = sh.Name
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "DeleteSheet"
End Sub
```

Comment: this event trigger each time i activate a sheet. Is there any other solution to avoid running the code each time?

Comment: @Error1004 instead of `Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal sh As Object)` in the above code use `Workbook_SheetBeforeDelete(ByVal Sh As Object)`

Comment: @Zsmaster to avoid trigger the code each time i activated a sheet u use **Workbook_SheetBeforeDelete(ByVal Sh As Object)** as per Siddharth Rout comment.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single event that captures either addition ([Workbook.NewSheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.newsheet)) or deletion ([Workbook.SheetBeforeDelete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetbeforedelete)). But you could detect both events separately, and run the same piece of code for both events.

To be able to run code *after* sheet deletion, you may use a timer to allow for deletion to take place.
Even better, you may set up a waiting loop that counts the number of sheets in the workbook, and which is only exited when the number of sheets is the expected number after deletion is completed. Then you execute your intended code.

Note that there is an issue when the deleted sheet is a `Chart`.
For those cases, you can use the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42160664/2707864).