# How can Excel send a notification to my Delphi app?

Tags: excel, delphi

I have a Delphi 10.4.1 app using `TExcelApplication`, `TExcelWorkbook` and `TExcelWorksheet`.

The Delphi app can read and write to Excel all OK.

What I would like is that if in Excel, the name of a worksheet is changed, added or deleted, then a "message" is sent to my Delphi app. I need a "trigger" and then my app can call `ExcelApplication1.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets` and get the list of worksheet names.

I thought about having a worker thread in my app call `ExcelApplication1.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets` in a loop and check for changes, but that doesn't seem very efficient. Especially considering that worksheet name changes aren't all that frequent.

Is there perhaps a Windows message that I could intercept?

Comment: Maybe [file change notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418562/delphi-notification-when-a-file-gets-updated) can help (of course it requires that you save the document).

Comment: What is the reason for this need? Depending on the real reason, there might be other ways to tackle the issue you have.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to create an automatable Delphi application and then invoke it from Excel (or any other application able to do automation) for example using a VBA macro. No need for a new application, you can add the feature to your existing application.

Here are the steps outlined:

1. Create a new `VCL forms application`
2. Add an `automation object`
3. Use the type library editor to add the API you'll call from VBA.
4. Implement the API
5. Compile
6. Register your application by running it from command line with admin priviledge and /REGSERVER as argument
7. Write a VBA macro calling your application (Using CreateObject to connect to your application).

You'll find detailed instructions at https://francois-piette.blogspot.com/2013/01/microsoft-word-or-excel-calls-delphi.html

Comment: And how will the VBA macro know that a worksheet has been deleted or renamed?

Comment: That is not the question you asked... And this is not a Delphi problem but an Excel problem. This other question has been answered there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156969/delete-sheet-chart-event-vba?rq=1

Comment: If my answer is acceptable for your question, please mark it as "accepted" (The check mark on the left of the answer). Thanks.

Comment: Good answer, but I am really trying to avoid having to use an Excel macro. I would prefer not to be adding anything to my customer's Excel.

Comment: @BobSmall: There is no other way to do what you're asking, whether you want to avoid it or not. There is no Windows message related to a third-party application (in this case Excel) doing something internally like changing data or adding a worksheet.